# Externally activate non-.NET application from Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

Can you externally activate a non-.NET app like Java or Python as easily you can a .NET app from Service Broker?  Are there any issues / concerns with doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external activation logic should apply in the same way. Once you have an sql server connection, everything is handled in t-sql and service broker objects.

[Event-Based Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171581.aspx)