# How does Sql server will identify Tomcat server?

Tags: sql-server, tomcat

I have number of applications in Tomcat server and I have sql server 2012 Database. Initially the Database will send the message to application says that database getting changed. Then the application(Tomcat server) fire the query to fetch the data from database.

In my scenario user doesn't have access to application(java, webMathematica, etc.) he has only access to Database to modify data. Initially I start the tomcat server and sql server then I can use JDBC driver to connect application server to sql server.

Now I want know whether database can identify the tomcat server before application server establish the connection to database server to send the message about the data updation.

Comment: Why does SQL server need to let the Tomcat Application know if the data has been updated on connection? Is the Tomcat app doing some kind of caching? or is the Tomcat app doing a custom process that needs to run when data has changed?

Comment: yes the Tomcat application does process when data got modified. Instead of application polling the Database for data updation, Application notify when the data got modify. [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207550/how-to-push-the-data-from-database-to-application)