# How can I write a query for notification request from application to Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

This is my perivous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207550/how-to-push-the-data-from-database-to-application) in stackoverflow about how to push the data from database instead of application pull data.

After went through the [link](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) and the documents I come to know that I need to write a query in application side for notification request then the DB will register my request in subscription and If there is any change in the DB it will check subscription, if the request is there it will send the message to the client.

This paragraph is from the above mentioned link:

> Along with the query submitted for the notification, the client submits a service name
>       and a broker instance. Each notification subscription begins a Service Broker dialog 
>       with this provided service and broker instance. When data is changed and the change 
>       would affect the result of the submitted query result, a message is sent on this  dialog. By sending this message, the client is considered notified and the notification 
>       subscription is removed. If client desires to be notified on further changes, is supposed to subscribe again.

Now I don't know how to write a query in application side for notification request and I don't under stand `submit a service and a broker instance` from the above given para. I guess the service and broker instance needs to be created in application before query the database for notification request. If it is so how to create service and a broker instance?

I can check the DB server for subscription by `select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` command. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For Service Broker, you can find a ASP.NET MVC based step by step guide [here](http://gavindraper.com/2012/06/03/sql-server-service-broker-explained/). It also links to a github [sample project](https://github.com/gavdraper/ServiceBrokerTicketMaster) for a better understand.
If you need just a callback to your SP/etc execution that's a [BeginExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx) command -from application side-.
If you need DTS event handling only (or on top of other things) it is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135967.aspx) with sample codes.
Hope this helps!