# Send message from database to activemq

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, activemq-classic

I have database `SQL Server 2012` and activemq installed in my system. I can able to send  message to activemq and receive message from activemq using java programs. I have written two java programs called MessageProducer and MessageConsumer for send and receive respectively. Now I want to send message from database to activemq, can anyone help me to do this?

Note: I can able to send and receive message in same database, I did this from following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207550/how-to-push-the-data-from-database-to-application). But it is in same database not even between different SQL Server. I guess I should use `endpoints` for server-server communication, I tried but I don't know how to use.

Feel comfortable to edit my question.

Thanks for take your time to see my question.

**Edit**: After little search I have done something like this to send message from database

```
--Create a Service Broker endpoint
USE master;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.endpoints
          WHERE name = N'InstInitiatorEndpoint')
 DROP ENDPOINT InstInitiatorEndpoint;
GO
CREATE ENDPOINT InstInitiatorEndpoint
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 61616 )
FOR SERVICE_BROKER (AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS );
GO

--Create the Initiator database, master key, and user
USE master;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases
       WHERE name = N'InstInitiatorDB')
 DROP DATABASE InstInitiatorDB;
GO
CREATE DATABASE InstInitiatorDB;
GO
USE InstInitiatorDB;
GO

CREATE MASTER KEY
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'<EnterStrongPassword2Here>';
GO
CREATE USER InitiatorUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO

--Create the Initiator certificate
CREATE CERTIFICATE InstInitiatorCertificate
 AUTHORIZATION InitiatorUser
 WITH SUBJECT = N'Initiator Certificate',
      EXPIRY_DATE = N'12/31/2013';

 BACKUP CERTIFICATE InstInitiatorCertificate
  TO FILE = 
  N'I:\MsSql\QueryNotification\InstTargetCertificate.cer';
GO


 --Create the message types

 CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//BothDB/2InstSample/RequestMessage]
   VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
 GO

--Create the contract
CREATE CONTRACT [//BothDB/2InstSample/SimpleContract]
  (     [//BothDB/2InstSample/RequestMessage]   SENT BY INITIATOR
  );
GO

--Create the Initiator queue and service

CREATE QUEUE InstInitiatorQueue;

CREATE SERVICE [//InstDB/2InstSample/InitiatorService]
   AUTHORIZATION InitiatorUser
   ON QUEUE InstInitiatorQueue;
GO


--Create routes

DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @Cmd = N'USE msdb
CREATE ROUTE InstInitiatorRoute
WITH SERVICE_NAME =
   N''//InstDB/2InstSample/InitiatorService'',
 ADDRESS = N''TCP://localhost:61616''';

EXEC (@Cmd);
GO
```

activemq tcp port is `tcp//localhost:61616` and my sql server running port is `1433`.
After this what should I do to send the message from sql server and see the message in activemq's queue?