# How to send data directly from MS SQL Server to android?

Tags: android, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to send data from MS SQL Server to an android app, and I've seen online tutorials so far, they only teach how the receive/insert data from/into MS SQL Server from the android side. Is there any way to send data to android from the SQL server side "live"?

In my context, I have a website created in visual studio with the sql server in the same project, and I want to send a notification to the android app upon clicking a button in the website.

For receiving data from MS SQL Server using android app, I used Microsoft's jtds driver, which I imported into the android app. Can this driver be used to receive data as well?

Comment: you can use firebase notifications for this...i dont know about MS jtds

Comment: @BipinGawand do you mean use firebase database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push the data from database to application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207550/how-to-push-the-data-from-database-to-application)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but i have no idea if this works with you db client.

You can use the SQL-Server Service Broker to send notifications to clients.
These notifications can triggered by table triggers like insert, update and delete.

[Service Broker @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[How to push the data from database to application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207550/how-to-push-the-data-from-database-to-application)